Is there a way to refresh a record after an autolaunched flow is executed?
I have a flow which is launched by a custom button in a record page. When the button is pressed it makes a field update. The problem is that after pressing it you can't see the update, but it's done (checked with Inspector). If you refresh the page you can see the changes. Is there a way to directly see the updated field after the button is pressed? I have checked that you can use an aura component to refresh the view but it is only available in screen flow at the moment.

Thanks for your help.
Edit
I have used a screen flow instead of an autolaunched and it is working, but the following screen appears after the page update is done. How can I remove it?


This question is similar to: Refresh the page after the flow completes. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Refer to this: https://salesforcetime.com/2023/03/21/a-flow-action-to-refresh-the-page/

@TusharJadav my issue is that I can't select my aura in the action block. It is not available.

Can your aura component implement lightning:availableForFlowActions?

Yes, it does. I have tested in a screen flow and I can select it but I can't in my autlaunched flow

My guess is that auto-launched flows cannot call Aura or LWC because auto-launched flows cannot interact with the UI.  I can't remember if there is a redirect action available in flow so you can redirect to the record page itself.

As per the Documentation, You can use the Aura Component as flow action in screen flow, not other types of flow.

Lightning components require a browser context to run, so flow action
components are supported only in screen flows.


There's no way to refresh the page in the autolaunched flow? Is it the only solution limited to Screen flows?

@AlejandroMartínezInfante, As per this, Recommended: Make it a screen flow. With no screens.

I have used a screen flow and now its working, but a screen appears when the update is made. You can check it in the question's edit.

@AlejandroMartínezInfante, You can check this for the ScreenFlow without a screen. - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007VJS2zSAH    -https://salesforcetime.com/2023/01/03/invisible-screen-flows/

I have already tried using an empty screen but after clicking the button a popup with the name of the flow still appears

You can use the Refresh API to request fresh data. If you are launching your flow from a quick action, it should be a LWC quick action instead so you can call the flow and then call the Refresh API.
